# how to remove particular element from unicode list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to remove specific value from a Unicode list i.e `field`

```
u'abv,( field),apn,army,elev,fema'
```

But when i try something like `result.remove ('(field)')` it stops working and gives an error ?

Comment: `string` object has no attribute 'remove' either use `replace` or convert it into list and then use `remove`

Comment: @akashkarothiya That sunds good Is my format remain sames 
because sometime it Will Not

Comment: yes the format remains same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert it into list and use `remove`

```
s = u'abv,( field),apn,army,elev,fema'
res = s.split(",")
res.remove("army") # lets assume we need to remove army
['abv', '( field)', 'apn', 'elev', 'fema']
```

You can make your output list back to string as well, if you wish

```
output = ",".join(res)
'abv,( field),apn,elev,fema'
```

Comment: Yes but it create an extra Comma ,, which create problem for me Can we totally  eliminate specific  word

Comment: i removed the 2nd method, use the above method

Comment: Agree Sir Thanks Alot Bro :) Please Up vote my Question